# Navigate programmatically through the records of a continuous form

Tags: forms, ms-access, navigation, ms-access-97

I would like to navigate through the records of a continuous form in Access 97. I don't find how to do it. This is what I tried:

`Me.RecordSetClone.MoveFirst` moves to the first record logically, but not in the UI. Also the `CurrentRecord` property does not change.

I cannot set the `CurrentRecord` property, it is readonly. `Me.CurrentRecord = 1` gives an error.

`DoCmd.GoToRecord Record:=acFirst` seems to have no effect.

What is the correct way to move to the first record in a continuous form (and to the next/previous)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Bookmark` property of RecordsetClone and Form.

Caveat: I'm pretty sure all this worked in Access 97, but that was a really long time ago.

```vb
Sub DemoNavigate()

    Dim RS As DAO.Recordset

    Set RS = Me.RecordsetClone
    RS.MoveFirst
    ' or
    RS.AbsolutePosition = 0

    ' Navigate in form
    Me.Bookmark = RS.Bookmark

    ' next record
    RS.MoveNext
    ' or
    RS.AbsolutePosition = 1

    Me.Bookmark = RS.Bookmark

    ' Move to searched record
    RS.FindFirst "someField = 42"
    Me.Bookmark = RS.Bookmark

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, `Bookmark` was the missing piece. I will give it a try.